# Animate change of view background color on Android

Tags: android, animation, view, background-color

How do you animate the change of background color of a view on Android?

For example:

I have a view with a red background color. The background color of the view changes to blue. How can I do a smooth transition between colors?

If this can't be done with views, an alternative will be welcome.

Comment: One would expect that a smooth transition between colors shouldn't be a problem for a platform like Android. Maybe views aren't built for it, though. The question still stands.

Comment: A good [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSgUn2rZiko)

Answer (score 427, accepted):

I ended up figuring out a (pretty good) solution for this problem!

You can use a [TransitionDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html) to accomplish this. For example, in an XML file in the drawable folder you could write something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- The drawables used here can be solid colors, gradients, shapes, images, etc. -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/original_state" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/new_state" />
</transition>
```

Then, in your XML for the actual View you would reference this TransitionDrawable in the `android:background` attribute.

At this point you can initiate the transition in your code on-command by doing:

```
TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) viewObj.getBackground();
transition.startTransition(transitionTime);
```

Or run the transition in reverse by calling:

```
transition.reverseTransition(transitionTime);
```

---

See [Roman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14467625/2359478) for another solution using the Property Animation API, which wasn't available at the time this answer was originally posted.

Comment: Thanks mxrider! This does answer the question. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me because the view that has the TransitionDrawable as background has to be animated as well, and it seems that the view animation overrides the background transition. Any ideas?

Comment: Solved it by starting the TransitionDrawable AFTER starting the animation.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it working! There is a lot of cool stuff you can do in xml with Android--much of which is kinda buried in the docs and not obvious in my opinion.

Comment: Not obvious at all. I should mention that I'm not using xml in my case, as the color is dynamic. Your solution also works if you create the TransitionDrawable by code.

Comment: Is it possible to use this method in a looping or auto-reversing like `UIView` animations on iOS?

Comment: It does not work *smoothly* cross-fade as I expected. using 4.1.2 device.

Comment: How about for a textview background animation from previous color to the next?

Comment: I had an xml as a drawable and wanted to change to another xml. This method works in such case.

Comment: @idolize i want this effect continuously . i tried it with a timer task . but it is not smooth. what am i suppose to do

Comment: One of the main drawbacks is that there is no animation complete listener

Comment: is it possible to animate more than 2 colors?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I waste 5 hours to find this solution

Answer (score 563):

You can use new [Property Animation Api](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) for color animation:

```
int colorFrom = getResources().getColor(R.color.red);
int colorTo = getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
colorAnimation.setDuration(250); // milliseconds
colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
        textView.setBackgroundColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());
    }

});
colorAnimation.start();
```

For backward compatibility with Android 2.x use [Nine Old Androids library](http://nineoldandroids.com/) from Jake Wharton.

The `getColor` method was deprecated in Android M, so you have two choices:

- If you use the support library, you need to replace the `getColor` calls with:

  ```
  ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red);
  ```
- if you don't use the support library, you need to replace the `getColor` calls with:

  ```
  getColor(R.color.red);
  ```

Comment: "musthave" solution if you are using Property Animation API (or NineOldAndroid). Animates very smoothly.

Comment: Is there any way to set the duration of the transition in this way?

Comment: @iGio90 yes, you are not not gonna believe it but the method call setDuration() :)

Comment: can i do this with drawables?

Comment: `ValueAnimator.ofArgb(colorFrom, colorTo)` looks more to the point, but sadly it's new.

Comment: To get current background color of layout, use this code. `((ColorDrawable)frame_layout.getBackground()).getColor()`

Comment: `ArgbEvaluator` is now private, don't use it. Legally reasons.

Comment: @PedroPauloAmorim why do you think it's now private? Documentation does not agree with you.

Comment: ArgbEvaluator from `android.animation` is not restricted, but the same class of `android.support.graphics.drawable` is tagged as `@RestrictTo(LIBRARY_GROUP)`. It generates a warning.

Comment: i want color change animation  like growing from bottom to top , how can i achieve that

Answer (score 150):

Depending on how your view gets its background color and how you get your target color there are several different ways to do this.

The first two uses the [Android Property Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) framework.

Use a [Object Animator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) if:

- Your view have its background color defined as a `argb` value in a xml file.
- Your view have previously had its color set by `view.setBackgroundColor()`
- Your view have its background color defined in a drawable that **DOES NOT** defines any extra properties like stroke or corner radiuses.
- Your view have its background color defined in a drawable and you want to remove any extra properties like stroke or corner radiuses, keep in mind that the removal of the extra properties will not animated.

The object animator works by calling `view.setBackgroundColor` which replaces the defined drawable unless is it an instance of a `ColorDrawable`, which it rarely is. This means that any extra background properties from a drawable like stroke or corners will be removed.

Use a [Value Animator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html) if:

- Your view have its background color defined in a drawable that also sets properties like the stroke or corner radiuses AND you want to change it to a new color that is decided while running.

Use a [Transition drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Transition) if:

- Your view should switch between two drawable that have been defined before deployment.

I have had some performance issues with Transition drawables that runs while I am opening a DrawerLayout that I haven't been able to solve, so if you encounter any unexpected stuttering you might have run into the same bug as I have.

You will have to modify the Value Animator example if you want to use a [StateLists drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) or a [LayerLists drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList), otherwise it will crash on the `final GradientDrawable background = (GradientDrawable) view.getBackground();` line.

**[Object Animator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html):**

View definition:

```
<View
    android:background="#FFFF0000"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>
```

Create and use a `ObjectAnimator` like this.

```
final ObjectAnimator backgroundColorAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(view,
                                                                       "backgroundColor",
                                                                       new ArgbEvaluator(),
                                                                       0xFFFFFFFF,
                                                                       0xff78c5f9);
backgroundColorAnimator.setDuration(300);
backgroundColorAnimator.start();
```

You can also load the animation definition from a xml using a AnimatorInflater like XMight does in [Android objectAnimator animate backgroundColor of Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097693/android-objectanimator-animate-backgroundcolor-of-layout)

**[Value Animator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html):**

View definition:

```
<View
    android:background="@drawable/example"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>
```

Drawable definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke
        android:color="#edf0f6"
        android:width="1dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="3dp"/>

</shape>
```

Create and use a ValueAnimator like this:

```
final ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(),
                                                           0xFFFFFFFF,
                                                           0xff78c5f9);

final GradientDrawable background = (GradientDrawable) view.getBackground();
currentAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(final ValueAnimator animator) {
        background.setColor((Integer) animator.getAnimatedValue());
    }

});
currentAnimation.setDuration(300);
currentAnimation.start();
```

**[Transition drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Transition):**

View definition:

```
<View
    android:background="@drawable/example"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>
```

Drawable definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
            <stroke
                android:color="#edf0f6"
                android:width="1dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#78c5f9"/>
            <stroke
                android:color="#68aff4"
                android:width="1dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</transition>
```

Use the TransitionDrawable like this:

```
final TransitionDrawable background = (TransitionDrawable) view.getBackground();
background.startTransition(300);
```

You can reverse the animations by calling `.reverse()` on the animation instance.

There are some other ways to do animations but these three is probably the most common. I generally use a ValueAnimator.

Comment: actually it is possible to define and use the TransitionDrawable in code, but for some reason, it doesn't work the second time. weird.

Comment: I am able to use the object animator even when my view has ColorDrawable set. I just save it to a local variable, set it to null and when the animation is finished, set the original ColorDrawable back.

Answer (score 61):

You can make an object animator. For example, I have a targetView and I want to change your background color:

```
int colorFrom = Color.RED;
int colorTo = Color.GREEN;
int duration = 1000;
ObjectAnimator.ofObject(targetView, "backgroundColor", new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo)
    .setDuration(duration)
    .start();
```

Comment: From API 21, you can use `ofArgb(targetView, "backgroundColor", colorFrom, colorTo)`. Its implementation is just `ofInt(...).setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator())`.

Answer (score 33):

If you want color animation like this,

[image]

this code will help you:

```
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);   
anim.setDuration(2000);

float[] hsv;
int runColor;
int hue = 0;
hsv = new float[3]; // Transition color
hsv[1] = 1;
hsv[2] = 1;
anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {

        hsv[0] = 360 * animation.getAnimatedFraction();

        runColor = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
        yourView.setBackgroundColor(runColor);
    }
});

anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

anim.start();
```

Comment: Where is the part when **anim** variable is initialized?

Comment: @VoW , it's just instance of ValueAnimator.

Comment: It should be `anim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);` not Animation.INFINITE for now it's the same, but we have no guarantees

Comment: @MikhailKrishtop what's wrong with Animation.INFINITE? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#INFINITE

Comment: is it possible to set as button background?

Answer (score 21):

best way is to use **ValueAnimator** and `ColorUtils.blendARGB`

```
 ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.0f, 1.0f);
 valueAnimator.setDuration(325);
 valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {

              float fractionAnim = (float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();

              view.setBackgroundColor(ColorUtils.blendARGB(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")
                                    , Color.parseColor("#000000")
                                    , fractionAnim));
        }
});
valueAnimator.start();
```

Comment: This solution is the best for multiple colors views animations with the same ValueAnimator Listener.

Comment: Set `valueAnimator.repeatCount = ValueAnimator.INFINITE` if you want repetition (for kotlin solution)

Comment: it work more smooth

Answer (score 21):

The documentation on XML powered animations is horrible. I've searched around hours just to animate the background color of a button when pressing... The sad thing is that the animation is only one attribute away: You can use `exitFadeDuration` in the `selector`:

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:exitFadeDuration="200">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:tint="#3F51B5" />
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:tint="#F44336" />
    </item>

</selector>
```

Then just use it as `background` for your view. No Java/Kotlin code needed.

Comment: Excellent answer. Note that you may need `android:enterFadeDuration` as well; my experience was that, without it, my animation didn't work the second time.

Comment: @String, strange, on an emulator it works many times without `android:enterFadeDuration`.

Answer (score 13):

Another easy way to achieve this is to perform a fade using AlphaAnimation.

1. Make your view a ViewGroup
2. Add a child view to it at index 0, with match_parent layout dimensions
3. Give your child the same background as the container
4. Change to background of the container to the target color
5. Fade out the child using AlphaAnimation.
6. Remove the child when the animation is complete (using an AnimationListener)

Answer (score 11):

Here's a nice function that allows this:

```
public static void animateBetweenColors(final @NonNull View viewToAnimateItsBackground, final int colorFrom,
                                        final int colorTo, final int durationInMs) {
    final ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(durationInMs > 0 ? colorFrom : colorTo);
    ViewCompat.setBackground(viewToAnimateItsBackground, colorDrawable);
    if (durationInMs > 0) {
        final ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
        colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(animator -> {
            colorDrawable.setColor((Integer) animator.getAnimatedValue());
            ViewCompat.setBackground(viewToAnimateItsBackground, colorDrawable);
        });
        colorAnimation.setDuration(durationInMs);
        colorAnimation.start();
    }
}
```

And in Kotlin:

```
@JvmStatic
fun animateBetweenColors(viewToAnimateItsBackground: View, colorFrom: Int, colorTo: Int, durationInMs: Int) {
    val colorDrawable = ColorDrawable(if (durationInMs > 0) colorFrom else colorTo)
    ViewCompat.setBackground(viewToAnimateItsBackground, colorDrawable)
    if (durationInMs > 0) {
        val colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo)
        colorAnimation.addUpdateListener { animator: ValueAnimator ->
            colorDrawable.color = (animator.animatedValue as Int)
            ViewCompat.setBackground(viewToAnimateItsBackground, colorDrawable)
        }
        colorAnimation.duration = durationInMs.toLong()
        colorAnimation.start()
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesnt support lower end version phones

Comment: @Kartheeks you mean Android 10 and below? if so, you can easily use a "nineOldAndroids" library to support it: http://nineoldandroids.com/ . the syntax is almost exactly the same.

Comment: for lower version 
colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    colorDrawable.setColor((Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                    ViewCompat.setBackground(viewToAnimateItsBackground, colorDrawable);
                }
            });

Answer (score 10):

This is the method I use in a Base Activity to change background. I'm using GradientDrawables generated in code, but could be adapted to suit.

```
    protected void setPageBackground(View root, int type){
        if (root!=null) {
            Drawable currentBG = root.getBackground();
            //add your own logic here to determine the newBG 
            Drawable newBG = Utils.createGradientDrawable(type); 
            if (currentBG==null) {
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
                    root.setBackgroundDrawable(newBG);
                }else{
                    root.setBackground(newBG);
                }
            }else{
                TransitionDrawable transitionDrawable = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[]{currentBG, newBG});
                transitionDrawable.setCrossFadeEnabled(true);
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
                     root.setBackgroundDrawable(transitionDrawable);
                }else{
                    root.setBackground(transitionDrawable);
                }
                transitionDrawable.startTransition(400);
            }
        }
    }
```

**update:** In case anyone runs in to same issue I found, for some reason on Android <4.3 using `setCrossFadeEnabled(true)` cause a undesirable white out effect so I had to switch to a solid colour for <4.3 using @Roman Minenok ValueAnimator method noted above.

Answer (score 9):

Answer is given in many ways. You can also use `ofArgb(startColor,endColor)` of `ValueAnimator`.

for API > 21:

```
int cyanColorBg = ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.cyan_bg);
int purpleColorBg = ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.purple_bg);

ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofArgb(cyanColorBg,purpleColorBg);
        valueAnimator.setDuration(500);
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
              @Override
              public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                   relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor((Integer)valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue());
              }
        });
        valueAnimator.start();
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the below function for Kotlin:

```
private fun animateColorValue(view: View) {
    val colorAnimation =
        ValueAnimator.ofObject(ArgbEvaluator(), Color.GRAY, Color.CYAN)
    colorAnimation.duration = 500L
    colorAnimation.addUpdateListener { animator -> view.setBackgroundColor(animator.animatedValue as Int) }
    colorAnimation.start()
}
```

Pass whatever view you want to change color of.

Answer (score 8):

[Roman Minenok](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14467625/6478047) answer in kotlin and as an extension function

```
fun View.colorTransition(@ColorRes startColor: Int, @ColorRes endColor: Int, duration: Long = 250L){
    val colorFrom = ContextCompat.getColor(context, startColor)
    val colorTo =  ContextCompat.getColor(context, endColor)
    val colorAnimation: ValueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofObject(ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo)
    colorAnimation.duration = duration

    colorAnimation.addUpdateListener {
        if (it.animatedValue is Int) {
            val color=it.animatedValue as Int
            setBackgroundColor(color)
        }
    }
    colorAnimation.start()
}
```

If you want  to change from current background color to new color then you can use this

```
fun View.colorTransition(@ColorRes endColor: Int, duration: Long = 250L){
    var colorFrom = Color.TRANSPARENT
    if (background is ColorDrawable)
        colorFrom = (background as ColorDrawable).color

    val colorTo =  ContextCompat.getcolor(context, endColor)
    val colorAnimation: ValueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofObject(ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo)
    colorAnimation.duration = duration

    colorAnimation.addUpdateListener {
        if (it.animatedValue is Int) {
            val color=it.animatedValue as Int
            setBackgroundColor(color)
        }
    }
    colorAnimation.start()
}
```

Usage

```
myView.colorTransition(R.color.bg_color)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use **ValueAnimator** like this:

```
 fun startColorAnimation(v: View) {
    val colorStart = v.solidColor
    val colorEnd = Color.RED
    val colorAnim: ValueAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(v, "backgroundColor", colorStart, colorEnd)
    colorAnim.setDuration(1000)
    colorAnim.setEvaluator(ArgbEvaluator())
    colorAnim.repeatCount = 1
    colorAnim.repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
    colorAnim.start()
}
```

Answer (score 6):

add a folder **animator** into **res** folder. (the name must be **animator**). Add an animator resource file. For example ***res/animator/fade.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="backgroundColor"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:valueFrom="#000000"
        android:valueTo="#FFFFFF"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:repeatCount="-1"
        android:repeatMode="reverse" />
</set>
```

Inside Activity java file, call this

```
View v = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
AnimatorSet set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.fade);
set.setTarget(v);
set.start();
```

Answer (score 5):

I've found that the implementation used by `ArgbEvaluator` in the Android source code does best job in transitioning colors. When using HSV, depending on the two colors, the transition was jumping through too many hues for me. But this method's doesn't.

If you are trying to simply animate, use `ArgbEvaluator` with `ValueAnimator` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14467625/2153244):

```
ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
        view.setBackgroundColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());
    }

});
colorAnimation.start();
```

However, if you are like me and want to tie your transition with some user gesture or other value passed from an input, the `ValueAnimator` is not of much help (unless your are targeting for API 22 and above, in which case you can use the [`ValueAnimator.setCurrentFraction()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#setCurrentFraction(float)) method). When targeting below API 22, wrap the code found in [`ArgbEvaluator` source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/animation/ArgbEvaluator.java) in your own method, as shown below:

```
public static int interpolateColor(float fraction, int startValue, int endValue) {
    int startA = (startValue >> 24) & 0xff;
    int startR = (startValue >> 16) & 0xff;
    int startG = (startValue >> 8) & 0xff;
    int startB = startValue & 0xff;
    int endA = (endValue >> 24) & 0xff;
    int endR = (endValue >> 16) & 0xff;
    int endG = (endValue >> 8) & 0xff;
    int endB = endValue & 0xff;
    return ((startA + (int) (fraction * (endA - startA))) << 24) |
            ((startR + (int) (fraction * (endR - startR))) << 16) |
            ((startG + (int) (fraction * (endG - startG))) << 8) |
            ((startB + (int) (fraction * (endB - startB))));
}
```

And use it however you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [ademar111190's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25693383/1617737), I have created this method the will pulse the background color of a view between any two colors:

```
private void animateBackground(View view, int colorFrom, int colorTo, int duration) {


    ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(view, "backgroundColor", new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
    objectAnimator.setDuration(duration);
    //objectAnimator.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    objectAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            // Call this method again, but with the two colors switched around.
            animateBackground(view, colorTo, colorFrom, duration);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
    objectAnimator.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ArgbEvaluatorCompat** class above API 11.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' 


ValueAnimator colorAnim = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluatorCompat(), startColor, endColor);
colorAnim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            mTargetColor = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        }
    });
colorAnim.start();
```