# TransitionDrawable doesn't account for padding?

Tags: android, button, padding, drawable, transition

I tried the accepted solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614545/animate-change-of-view-background-color-in-android), but it appears to ignore padding. When the second view (in this case a button) displays, it's much smaller than the original which has padding. Is there a workaround for that? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `TransitionDrawable` extends from `LayerDrawable` which ignores the padding. This is the `getPadding()` method in the base Android code, which gets rid of anything you specified:

```
    @Override
    public boolean getPadding(Rect padding) {
        // Arbitrarily get the padding from the first image.
        // Technically we should maybe do something more intelligent,
        // like take the max padding of all the images.
        padding.left = 0;
        padding.top = 0;
        padding.right = 0;
        padding.bottom = 0;
        final ChildDrawable[] array = mLayerState.mChildren;
        final int N = mLayerState.mNum;
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            reapplyPadding(i, array[i]);
            padding.left += mPaddingL[i];
            padding.top += mPaddingT[i];
            padding.right += mPaddingR[i];
            padding.bottom += mPaddingB[i];
        }
        return true;
    }
```

See [base Android code here](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/donut/frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.java).

To deal with it, I had to first save the padding values before setting the faulty drawable background on my view:

```
    int bottom = theView.getPaddingBottom();
    int top = theView.getPaddingTop();
    int right = theView.getPaddingRight();
    int left = theView.getPaddingLeft();
    theView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.faulty_drawable);
    theView.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  However, I'm using the method mentioned in the supplied link, so I have something like:

TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) btnTransition.getBackground();
transition.startTransition(200);

So, I save the paddings before the transition and then set the paddings afterward.  I guess I'm using it wrong, because it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, there's no "solution" (and this is a bug, in my eyes). What I meant is that you first need to set the background to another `Drawable` (that's not a `LayerDrawable`) which has the padding values that you want, _then_ you can save the padding values and restore them after you set your `TransitionDrawable`. Or, alternatively, you can set the padding values to the dimensions that you want. In my case, I always had a previous drawable to get the right padding values from.

Comment: I guess I understand.  Sounds like I cannot do it with a button at all.  Sorry, still getting used to Android development.