# Adding PNG and color to background

Tags: android

I have LinearLayout, and I have png that I used as tiles - but i want also that the color behind it will be white.

Is that possible?

My code is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/LinearMain" android:background="@drawable/bcktiles">
```

and the drawable is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/bgsite" android:tileMode="repeat">
    </bitmap>
```

I dont know where to put #fff

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also create a composite drawable by doing:

`drawable/composite.xml`:

```
<layer-list 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="color drawable" />
    <item android:drawable="drawable 1..." />
</layer-list>
```

And for your color, you can create a shape drawable:

```
<shape 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="color" />
</shape>
```

Comment: This is a good choice, just watch out for [disappearing padding values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104677/transitiondrawable-doesnt-account-for-padding/6105149#6105149).

Comment: I have it well on the eclipse preview screen but when laucnhing on XOOM i see only white!

Comment: You may be bitten by this bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15340

Answer (score 0):

In your LinearLayout, you'd want to use `android:background="@color/myColor"` if you're referencing a color resource. You can also just put `android:background="#FFFFFFFF"` if you don't want to store it as a resource.

Comment: but then im replacing the drawable reference!

Comment: You've only really got one spot to put a background in a LinearLayout, so you'd have to choose between a color or tiles. Why not use a RelativeLayout, set the background to your color, and then put an ImageView in it that is set to FILL_PARENT that shows your tiles? That way, you can still put other views overtop of the tiles.