# Button Animation in Android on State change

Tags: android, android-animation

Hi i have a button with an enabled state and disabled state.initially it will be in disabled state as shown below

[image: Disabled State]

At a particular time i need to enable it as shown below

[image: Enabled State]

I want to animate this state change

This is my Invalid Drawable :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</shape>
```

And below is my Enabled State :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</shape>
```

how can i animate this state change on an event trigger??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animate selector/state transitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221535/animate-selector-state-transitions)

Comment: @0X0nosugar i need to have this on text change or some validation...

Comment: I thought the first answer might be what you're looking for: *TransitionDrawables*. They can be started programmatically:  transition.startTransition(transitionTime);  But maybe the link-to-another-answer in that first answer is even more helpful.

Comment: @0X0nosugar im able to achieve the result using TransitionDrawable as metioned... have pasted the code below.. thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to achieve the result using TransitionDrawable

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) btnSignIn.getBackground();
                transition.startTransition(1000);
                btnSignIn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }, 1000);
```

and my new drawable is like :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- The drawables used here can be solid colors, gradients, shapes, images, etc. -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/invalid_button" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/valid_button" />
</transition>
```

Where invalid_button.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</shape>
```

And valid_button.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</shape>
```