# Android change color of ImageView / Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview

I need to find a way to change the color of bitmap in Android. I need to replace/change colors of oval image smoothly in my application depending on `int` value. I need something like if `myValue=5` than change my image's color to `RED` and if `myValue=322` change color to `BLUE`. The only way which I find I can do this was using xml file which looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval" android:padding="10dp">
<!-- you can use any color you want I used here gray color-->
 <solid android:color="#cccccc"/> 
    <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
     android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
     android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

and after that when `myValue` is changing to set my `ImageView` image resource. But in this way I have to create 35 different xml files...which I don't think is a good idea.

So anyone who can suggest better solution to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is how I solved this issue :

1. Declare an `ImageView` with `src="@drawable/button"`
2. Create a `Drawable` and set `ColorFilter` to it and after that use it as src to your declared `ImageView` like this :

>

```
Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.button );
ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter( Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE );
myIcon.setColorFilter(filter);
color.setImageDrawable(myIcon);
```

Comment: Can you also mention how to do this in the xml if its possible?

Comment: Nvm I found it, have to use the the `android:tint` attribute for `imageview`

Answer (score 16):

This solution doesn't work very well for me. In some images the final color was wrong.
I use this solution instead:

```
Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_image); 
myIcon.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); 
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.view_to_change)).setImageDrawable(myIcon);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.button );
```

is now deprecated. Can also do it this way:

```
((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_icon))
  .setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE));
```

Answer (score 1):

Should you this.

```
Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.button ); 
ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter( Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);
myIcon.setColorFilter(filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TransitionDrawable to achieve this - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html

Comment: I saw that option but didn't find any good example or explanation how to use it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614545/animate-change-of-view-background-color-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private final ImageView uiIV_statusIcon;
uiIV_statusIcon = anyView.findViewById(R.id.iv_status);
uiIV_statusIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_twotone_error_24);
```

in Activity:

```
ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(uiIV_statusIcon, ColorStateList.valueOf(getColor(R.color.md_red_400)));
```

in a Fragment

```
ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(uiIV_statusIcon, ColorStateList.valueOf(getContext().getColor(R.color.md_red_400)));
```

in a Recyclerviewadapter with preassigned variable _context :

```
ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(uiIV_statusIcon, ColorStateList.valueOf(_context.getColor(R.color.md_red_400)));
```