# How change ActionBar colour when swiping between fragments (Material Design)?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragmentpageradapter, material-design

I have an app i am doing, which has a FragmentPagerAdapter setup with 3 fragments to swipe between on the main page.

I have been trying to get it setup so as you swipe between fragments, the action bar changes color (fades in and out).

However i am not sure how i should do this.
What method is called when you swipe between fragments? I.E where should i put the code to change the action bar colour?

And also how would i get the fade in and out effect (so it fades out one colour into another one)?

I would really appreciate anyones help.

Thanks in advance

Cheers
Corey :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What method is called when you swipe between fragments?

You're looking for [`ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageScrolled(int,%20float,%20int)). This will give you:

- **position**  Position index of the first page currently being displayed.
- **positionOffset** Value from [0, 1) indicating the offset from the page at position.
- **positionOffsetPixels** Value in pixels indicating the offset from position.

Although, you'll only need the first two parameters. What you'll want to do is bind a particular color to each of your fragments, retrieve both the current page and next page colors, then blend them together using the `positionOffset` ratio to create your new `ActionBar` background.

A useful algorithm for blending two colors based on a ratio can be found in Google's new [`SlidingTabStrip`](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabStrip.html) example. `0.0` will return the second color, `0.5` will return an even blend, and `1.0` will return the first color

```
static int blendColors(int from, int to, float ratio) {
    final float inverseRation = 1f - ratio;
    final float r = Color.red(from) * ratio + Color.red(to) * inverseRation;
    final float g = Color.green(from) * ratio + Color.green(to) * inverseRation;
    final float b = Color.blue(from) * ratio + Color.blue(to) * inverseRation;
    return Color.rgb((int) r, (int) g, (int) b);
}
```

Here's a simple example:

**ColorFragment**

```
public class ColorFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String KEY_COLOR = "colorfragment:color";

    /** Empty constructor as per the {@link Fragment} docs */
    public ColorFragment() {
    }

    public static ColorFragment newInstance(int color) {
        final Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(KEY_COLOR, color);
        final ColorFragment fragment = new ColorFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final FrameLayout rootView = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        rootView.setBackgroundColor(getArguments().getInt(KEY_COLOR));
        return rootView;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return getArguments().getInt(KEY_COLOR);
    }

}
```

**Pulling it all together**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set the ActionBar background
    final ColorDrawable actionBarBackground = new ColorDrawable();
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(actionBarBackground);
    ...
    final PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = ...;
    ...
    // Bind your data to your PagerAdapter
    ...
    final ViewPager pager = ...;
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
            if (position >= pagerAdapter.getCount() - 1) {
                // Guard against ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
                return;
            }
            // Retrieve the current and next ColorFragment
            final ColorFragment from = (ColorFragment) pagerAdapter.getItem(position);
            final ColorFragment to = (ColorFragment) pagerAdapter.getItem(position + 1);
            // Blend the colors and adjust the ActionBar
            final int blended = blendColors(to.getColor(), from.getColor(), positionOffset);
            actionBarBackground.setColor(blended);
        }

    });
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
}
```

**Results**

http://gfycat.com/CautiousBewitchedJabiru

I hope that helps you out some!

Comment: Hey, that was perfext! Thanks heaps for your help. Corey :)

Comment: ViewPage setOnPageChangeListener is deprecated, use addOnPageChangeListener method instead

Answer (score 1):

You could make your FragmentPagerAdapter implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.

Then, override onPageSelected

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // get the action bar here and change color
}
```

As for the color change animation. I didn't try it, but this is from another stackoverflow issue :

[Android objectAnimator animate backgroundColor of Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097693/android-objectanimator-animate-backgroundcolor-of-layout)