# highlight background effect

Tags: android, effect

Is there an Android effect to highlight a background like with jQuery :
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight
I want to make a degrade on a Layout when I click on it...

Or do we have to do it programmatically?

Comment: You can try to do it using animation. Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614545/animate-change-of-view-background-color-in-android is pretty good sample.

Comment: Thank you, I had not seen it...