# Textview Background does not work

Tags: android, listview, gridview, textview

I’m one of Chinese Engineer and My English Speaking is not so good.
There is a ListView having some(three or two) GridView Items, and each GridView have some TextView Items.

Now I want to Set the this TextView Item's border-color like the picture [refer screenchot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPbXF.png) then I made some drawable like this [code-pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCyhA.png)

I set the Item's backgroud property with this drawable. When I was running the app, all of things were working well, but when I click those items found it was not working. There was no border and color change.

How to achive this?

Comment: post your java code

Comment: I realized that the first pic may  mislead you, you just need see the top 6 items. i want if i click one of this 6, it's color was set as blue , and the others' boder disapeared

Comment: on clicking textview you have to put yourtextview.setSelected(true); then you will get your result.

Comment: i tried , maybe it is what i want ,  i set property  textview.setSelected(true),   it works. but there is a new problem  and i know how to solve it  , thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this create drawble file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

apply to your textview

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `android:state_pressed` in your dataset_setting_button_selector.xml instead of `android:state_activated`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html

Comment: thank you for your answer ,  when i pressed  it is changed , but when i relaxed my finger it changed back.

Comment: then remove android:state_pressed="false" from your xml

Comment: u can also look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936597/changing-textview-background-color-on-click-android