# Fade transition in a TextView background color

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` which changes color based on value given by a `SeekBar`:

```
if ((inOne >= 70 && inOne <= 90) && (inTwo >= 40 && inTwo <= 60)) {
            tvRes.setText("LOW");
            tvRes.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#73539E"));
            rlO.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9973539E"));
        }
        if ((inOne >= 70 && inOne <= 90) && (inTwo >= 61 && inTwo <= 80)) {
            tvRes.setText("IDEAL");
            tvRes.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#679800"));
            rlO.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#99679800"));
        }
        if ((inOne >= 70 && inOne <= 90) && (inTwo >= 81 && inTwo <= 90)) {
            tvRes.setText("PRE-HIGH");
            tvRes.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#967400"));
            rlO.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#99967400"));
        }
```

`inOne` and `inTwo` are `SeekBar` values.

It works 100% without any issue. What I was looking to do, instead of just changing the color, I want it to animate fade from one color to the next. How can I achieve it?

I was looking at this example: [SO Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614545/animate-change-of-view-background-color-in-android) wasn't too clear on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently made a helper class to animate between colours, and you can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/amlcurran/5560546). Perhaps it can be of some use?

As for how to use it, it is very similar in usage to other Animators:

```
ColorAnimator.ofColor(view, "color", Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE).start();
```

for a background color, use a ViewBackgroundWrapper (**EDIT** or the new convenience method):

```
ColorAnimator.ofBackgroundColor(tvRes, Color.parseColor("#679800")).start();
```

This would animate the first background color in your code snippet.

Comment: Wow... might just work... Can I use color.xml color names instead of the pre defined colors? Can you provide an example from the code I provided? thanks.

Comment: Yup, you can use any color returned as an int (from resources, or Color.parse()). Added an example.

Comment: no, you're not doing something wrong - I can't get it working either! Give me a while, and I'll get back to you :)

Comment: PHEW :)... I thought I was doing it wrong... lol... I will wait! :)

Comment: Any idea when you might have this completed? :)P

Comment: Hi... Any update on if you have it working? I will accept your answer because you helped.