# How to set layout background fade out?

Tags: android

I added an option menu in my app.

I want activity's whole background appear dark when menu key is touched so the user can see option menu well.(like when a dialog is displayed)

Should I use animation to do this or is there any other way?

Comment: I would use animation, you could also use transition drawable: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3208800/2023280

Comment: In the link Djordje mentioned, The answer right below the answer he mentioned is great. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using `OptionMenu`, you could do:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.your_option_menu:         
        mRootLayout.setAlpha(0.5f);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

`mRootLayout` would be the root layout from the xml you set the view in your activity. Just use `findViewById` to set it.

After you select a final option in your menu, make sure to return the `alpha` property of the root layout to 1.