# Animate navigation bar color Android

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have in my styles

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="MYTheme" parent="...">
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/navigationBarColor</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I know I can change the color of the navigation bar with

```
getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(...);
```

I want change the color with an animation, a transition between the current color and the new color

Comment: I think objectAnimator wil help you

Comment: @Nilesh can you provide an example?

Answer (score 6):

You can animate color change using `ValueAnimator.ofArgb`. I must mention that it is supported only beginning with API >= 21. This shouldn't be a problem, though, because `setNavigationBarColor` is >= 21 too.

```
int from = getWindow().getNavigationBarColor();
int to = Color.BLACK; // new color to animate to

ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofArgb(from, to);
colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor((Integer) animator.getAnimatedValue());
    }
});
colorAnimation.start();
```

Comment: Look at my answer and check how to make it API 11+ compatible.

Comment: @joaquin, your answer is still 21+ only, because `setNavigationBarColor` is 21+.

Answer (score 0):

I agree partially with Egor N's answer. But my answer will make your app compatible backwards to API 11 instead of 21, as he suggests.

I share [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14467625/2823516)

```
Integer colorFrom = getWindow().getNavigationBarColor();
Integer colorTo = Color.BLACK;
ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor((Integer) animator.getAnimatedValue());
    }

});
colorAnimation.start();
```