# Android image progress bar, change from black and white to colour

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an android app that uploads multiple files to a cloud platform.  As a progress bar i want to take an image that is black and white, originally colour.  As the upload progresses i'd like to return the image back to its colour.  Something similar to filling a jug with water, i.e. colour fills from the bottom to the top, if that makes sense.

I'm looking for someone to point me in the right direction.  I'm not sure where to start.

Thank you!

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614545/animate-change-of-view-background-color-in-android

Comment: I had already seen that, it didn't help unfortunately.