# Android Studio - access main loop

Tags: android, android-studio, program-entry-point, event-based-programming

mainly just looking for the place where I can call a method every single loop. I'd like to increase/decrease the Y of a button over a period of time. Can this be done without an event system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Android Animations, it's the easiest approach for what I think you need to implement.

Check out: http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=952

#### Overview

Create an animation XML file, specify `toYDelta` and duration as required.

Then load the animation and start it when required,

`Animation animation
    = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation);`
 `animBtn.startAnimation(animation);`

To call a method for each iteration of a loop,

Look here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-run-a-task-periodically-in-java/

My personal choice is using a handler: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-run-a-task-periodically-in-java/

Morever, if you are willing to cause a delay in your main thread to delay method calls, I would advice against that.

Comment: Ok, I see how that could be useful, but what if I wanted to do something else, like change the background color continuously?

Comment: Is there a way to write in non-event-based methods?

Comment: You can use `Transition Drawable` to accomplish that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614545/animate-change-of-view-background-color-in-android

Comment: Periodic call to a method call can be accomplished by several means, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614545/animate-change-of-view-background-color-in-android What do you mean my non event based?

Comment: By that I meant something that runs all the time and not just fired by an event listener

Comment: Well, go through the link I have provided in answer, it explains how to run a handler in background. You can run it in background for as long as you want, without hindering your main thread. Moreover, you don't need a listener to run a handler, you can start it whenever you want.