# How can I animate the color of Floating Action Button

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

I want to change to color of the floating action button continuously with some time elapsed.

Comment: use `ValueAnimator ` / `ObjectAnimator` then

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animate change of view background color in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614545/animate-change-of-view-background-color-in-android)

Comment: Use Material Color Palett to change to color of the floating action button

Comment: Above methods are not working