# How to implement animations/transitions in Android

Tags: android, animation, transition

I have a specific goal regarding animation using Recyclerview, but I cant find an exact title to convey my concern, so I'm open to any correction if necessary. So first , I have a recyclerview that acts as a ViewPager thanks to [David Medenjak's Recyclerview ViewPager](https://blog.davidmedenjak.com/android/2017/06/24/viewpager-recyclerview.html)

Now I have a requirement to animate the background color for each swipe transition, thanks to different links and resources, I stumbled upon TransitionDrawables, putting an array of different drawables and invoking a necessary transition functions to animate,

```
recyclerView.setBackground(arrayOfDrawables)
transitionArrayOfDrawables.startTransition(...);
```

Now I want to take things deeper, **I want to manually control the transition relative to the animation of the swipe of each item of the recyclerview**, Im mentally blocked as I cant find the keyword to search for where should I start, "Interpolation", "Manually interpolating a views animation", things like that, but still no luck, the only thing that I have on my mind is "**Get the recyclerview's visible item's interpolation/animation-value then supply it to the target view's animation manually"**, but I dont know where to start, I dont even know how to animate view's manually, I have experience with ObjectAnimators, simple translating, scaling, bouncing etc.. but controlling view's animation manually and relatively even by using knob/seek bar or such,  its just out of my domain as of the moment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Edit] Apologies if my question's intent covers alot of demands :(

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, [this](http://kubaspatny.github.io/2014/09/18/viewpager-background-transition/) link may be of some use. It provides instruction for how to gradually transition between viewpager background colors in relation to the user swipe.

The example uses the [ArgbEvaluator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ArgbEvaluator) class which -according to the doc: "...perform[s] type interpolation between integer values that represent ARGB colors."

Comment: thanks so much! I also stumbled with this S.O question which is closely related to the link you gave, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614545/animate-change-of-view-background-color-on-android/14467625#14467625, now Im having a lead towards animating colors, but I hope someone can also point me on how to manually animate a view/object relative to some external source :(

Comment: Oh and as well as get the Recyclerview's animating value/properties during dragging/swiping.. :(