# Fill screen with a color progressively when pressing the screen event triggred

Tags: android

I want the screen of my android app to be filled with a color progressively like a radial gradient or  a circle that grows progressively.

Any ideas or help please.

Comment: I would advice to add some code you have tried into your question. It will increase the chance of getting an answer and reduce the chance of having your question flagged and removed.

Comment: You can do it with value animator or transition drawables. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614545/animate-change-of-view-background-color-on-android