# Animating a button background to reflect time left?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, animation, android-7.1-nougat

I am working on a android project where the user can scan a RFID tag. The tag expires after a certain amount of seconds to clear up the system before another tag comes in, basically to avoid processing the same tag twice by mistake. To visualise this timeout I want the background of the button where the tags ID is displayed to be animated. Basically I want the entire button to be filled with color when the tag has just been scanned and slowly scale down to the middle as time processes.

[image: Diagram of what I am looking for]

**What I have found so far:**
I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14467625/6063262) where they talk about the properties api. I could see this working with a gradient but unfortunately the documentation on gradients is sparce and it looks like it wouldnt be that easy to do that with.

I also thought that maybe you could achieve this by somehow layering another view of the same size below the button and scaling that. But honestly I think this would be quite difficult to do consistently, especially with resizing the view while the timer processes and configuration changes. Then again, I am not really that experienced with android and use linear and grid layouts for almost everything since they are the easiest to understand.

All I would really need is some way to essentially "scale" the background by a value (the ratio between total time and time left) towards the middle like I have demonstrated here. Or a way to essentially have a hard color gradient where the white portions of the gradient move towards the middle as the time processes.

Last solution I thought could maybe work is to have a animated vector drawable and manipulate the objectanimator associated with it to force it to play at the right speed. However, this solution is probably pretty messy, thought I haven't tried it (yet)

Does anyone have a clean solution to this problem?

**Note: i am using java for this project. I did not include code snippets because I didn't think they were needed. If you need some snippets please simply ask and I will provide. My minSdkVersion is 25 since the target device for the job has android 7.1 and cannot be updated to a newer version.**

Comment: I would just use a horizontal progress bar instead and a timer that updates its progress from 100 to 0 percent as time runs out. If you want to have the progress reset in the middle, use two progress bars side by side

Comment: @NikosHidalgo Great idea. I will attempt this and report back. However, I am confused as to how it should work with 2 progress bars. I cannot span the text over 2 view elements :/

Comment: The "button" can be **any** clickable View. An ImageView could be the trick. Or even a LinearLayout with an ImageView which shrinks down.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a sample layout with two progress bars and a textview over them:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/transparent"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:scaleY="4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/progressBar2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView2"
        tools:progress="100" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/transparent"
        android:scaleY="4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/progressBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView2"
        tools:progress="100" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

These are the results you get by setting the progress to 100, 50 and 1:

100:

[image]

50:

[image]

1:

[image]

If you add a custom drawable as your background you can make the progress bar fill the space accordingly and also make its colour red.

**Note** that the grey lines in the photos are from my design tab in Android Studio and aren't visible other than when debugging.

UPDATE: Here's the animation code that makes the progress bars reset from 100% to 0% in 5 seconds.

ProgressBar pb = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        ProgressBar pb2 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);

```
    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(pb, "progress", 0, 100);
    animation.setDuration(5000);
    animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animation.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) { }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            //do something when the countdown is complete
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) { }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) { }
    });
    animation.start();

    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set.playTogether(ObjectAnimator.ofInt(pb, "progress", 100, 0),
            ObjectAnimator.ofInt(pb2, "progress", 100, 0));
    set.setDuration(5000);
    set.start();
```